# Covert NAs to a separate level in each variable using mutate()

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have 12 variables that contained NA values as well. I need to covert NAs to a separate level. Level value for some variables is different. Following is the code:

```
Replace_NAs <- function(colindex, na_level){
  cname <- colnames(tr[colindex])
  tr <- tr %>% mutate(cname = as.factor(replace(cname, is.na(cname), na_level)))
  return(tr)
}

for (i in 1:12) {
  if(i == 5){
      na_level <- 3;
      tr <- Replace_NAs(i,na_level);
  }
  else if(i == 11){
    na_level <- 5;
    tr <- Replace_NAs(i,na_level);
  }
  else if(i == 4|6|8){
    na_level <- 1;
    tr <- Replace_NAs(i,na_level);
  }
  else{
    na_level <- 20;
    tr <- Replace_NAs(i,na_level);
  }
}
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Please, include a reproducible example of your data and the desired output. With that, help you would be a lot easier.

Comment: Apologize for the way of presenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do this using a `for` loop.

Consider this example :

```
tr <- data.frame(a = c(NA, 2, NA, 3), b = c(2, 3, NA, 4), 
                 c = c(5, 6, NA, NA), d = c(1, 2, 3, NA))
tr
#   a  b  c  d
#1 NA  2  5  1
#2  2  3  6  2
#3 NA NA NA  3
#4  3  4 NA NA
```

Now prepare a list of column indices and a vector of replacement values

```
cols <- list(1, c(2, 3))
vals <- c(3, 5)
```

Use a `for` loop to replace the columns with the values

```
for(i in seq_along(cols)) {
  tr[cols[[i]]][is.na(tr[cols[[i]]])] <- vals[i]
}
```

For remaining columns

```
f_cols <- setdiff(seq_len(ncol(tr)), unlist(cols))
tr[f_cols][is.na(tr[f_cols])] <- 20

tr
#  a b c  d
#1 3 2 5  1
#2 2 3 6  2
#3 3 5 5  3
#4 3 4 5 20
```

You can notice how `NA`'s in column 1 is replaced with 3, how `NA`'s in column 2 and 3 are replaced with 5 and for rest of the column it is replaced by 20.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @Ronak. It works. Can I use the above for loop code for other functions; eg: relevel function instead of is.na()

Comment: Yes, you can probably ask it as a new question with the details.

Answer (score 1):

As Johan mentioned in the comments, you should include a reproducible example. Without that, we're left guessing at what exactly you want.

That said, here's my guess at what'll help you:

```r
df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(5), ~ replace_na(., 3)) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(11), ~ replace_na(., 5)) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(4, 6, 8) ~ replace_na(., 1)) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(-c(4, 5, 6, 8, 11)), ~ replace_na(., 20))
```

Again, please provide a reproducible example with data and your desired output. A more robust answer to your question would explore applying a list of intended switches to your dataframe, but that would be overkill here.